Google Sheet Script Not Sending Email in Form Order & Bolding Text
I have a Google Form that is linked to a Sheet. I need an email sent with the form answers immediately after submittal of the form. I have a script that does that, but it does not send the questions/responses in the same order as they are in the form. Also, I would like the questions to be bolded, and the responses not bolded.
Here's the script I'm working with:
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var message = 'New Work Order Request: \n\n';
  for (var question in e.namedValues) {
    if (question !== '') message += `${question}: ${e.namedValues[question]}\n`;
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail(),'New Work Order Request',     message);
}

I would like the content of the email sent to contain the questions in order that they are in the form, and the questions of the form to be bolded in that email.
I don't know much about coding so I'm having a hard time with this.

Would you mind providing a sample question for the form?

The questions are:
-Email address
-Name
-Phone Number
-Location of Request
-Description of Request
-Alternate POC

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Edit the question instead of posting the update as a comment so that crucial information won't be left out. If the posted answer also helped you out, consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark on it's left.

Use HTML <b> Tag
You may use this modified version of your script that should work with what your desired outcome. The script will transmit the questions/responses in the order they appear in the form and the questions will be bolded.
Code:
 function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var message = "<p><b>New Work Order Request:</b></p>";
  var form = FormApp.openById('YOUR_FORM_ID'); //replace with your Form ID
  var items = form.getItems();
  
  items.forEach(item => {
    var question = item.getTitle(); 
    var response = e.namedValues[question] ? e.namedValues[question].join(', ') : "No response"; 
    message += `<b> ${question}: </b> ${e.namedValues[question]}<br>`;
  });

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to:Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail(),
    subject: 'New Work Order Request',
    htmlBody: message,
  });
}

Note: Ensure your script includes an installable trigger, as shown below:

Choose which function to run: onFormSubmit
Which runs at deployment: Head
Select event source: From spreadsheet
Select event type: On form submit

Reference:
HTML  Tag

An answer has been posted in response to your question. Please review the answer if it correctly solves your issue. If it does, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and/or upvote the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that their issue can be resolved. For further details, you may read the article on how to accept the answer.
